# Tmux window or pane name won't change in GNOME Terminal

Tags: tmux, gnome-terminal, fedora-25

Using Fedora 25 and GNOME Terminal. I have used Tmux for a few years in Ubuntu with a long customized `.tmux.conf` file. Recently installed Tmux and Tmuxinator in Fedora.

When I open the Terminal. I see that the title is set to `tom@localhost:~`. When I create a new Tmux session such as `tmux new -s panes`. The title of the pane is still `tom@localhost:~`.

Inside the Tmux session. When I open a new window with name `console` like this `new-window -n console`. The title won't change to `console` and keeps saying `tom@localhost:~`.

I thought maybe tmux is not overriding the titles so I added this to the `tmux.conf` file:

```
set-option -g set-titles on
set -g terminal-overrides "xterm*:XT:smcup@:rmcup@"
```

That still doesn't do anything.

The Terminal settings. I have `Profile/Command/When terminal commands set their own titles` set to `Replace initial title`.

I cannot figure this out. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure why it works. But this solves my problem.

Inside the `.tmux.conf` file I added the line `set-option -g allow-rename off`. At the top of the file I had the line `set -g default -terminal "xterm"`. I removed this line.